# Is present perfect necessarily definitive action in past

Tags: present-perfect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the tenses in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

If I say "I have worked in a supermarket." does it mean that all the work is in the past and that now, I definitely do not work in a supermarket?

Comment: Ordinarily, *I have worked [somewhere]* does indeed mean this was something in the past that no longer applies. But there are exceptions. For example, suppose you had worked in a supermarket some time ago, and today you've just started *another* job in a supermarket. The manager starts telling you a lot of details about how to do the job. You could say to him *"I have worked in a supermarket before, so I already know all this."* Even though at the time of speaking now you *are* working in a supermarket (I think it would have to be a different one, though, for that to work).

Comment: @Mahnax: Thank you so much for turning up that original! I think we'll be redirecting a *lot* of questions there in future!

Comment: @FumbleFingers—Just doing my duty, sir.

Answer (score 3):

> Is present perfect necessarily definitive action in past?

No. The present perfect tense is used in many occasions for something that started in the past **and continues in the present**. For example:

- I have lived all my life in this little city.
- I have worked here since 2009.
- **I have worked in supermarkets all my life.**
- It has been raining for hours.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on context: "I have kept your trust" does not imply I am now betraying you, but "I have read your book" does imply that I have finished reading your book.